# How to change object attribute in update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I need to use method, which is working only in controller, but I can't implement changing attribute.

Here is my update action:

```
def update
@website = Website.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
 if @website.update_attributes(params[:website]) 
  if params[:website][:language] == "Auto"
    @website.[:website][:language] =  full_language("request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first")
  end

    format.html { redirect_to @website, notice: 'website was successfully updated.' }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.js { render action: "edit" }
  end
end
```

end

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@website.update_attributes(params[:website])
```

already performs the save to the database.

```
@website.[:website][:language] =  full_language("request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first")
```

doesn't make any sense.

```
@website.language = full_language(request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first)
```

does. Also note the removal of quotes before `request.env`. Beware that you need to save again the changes, so it makes sense to move everything before the update attributes and use one single save call.

```
def update
  @website = Website.find(params[:id])
  @website.attributes = params[:website]

  if params[:website][:language] == "Auto"
    @website.language = full_language(request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
   if @website.save
    format.html { redirect_to @website, notice: 'website was successfully updated.' }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.js { render action: "edit" }
  end
end
```

Last but not least, you might want to stop for a second and learn a little bit of Ruby syntax and ActiveRecord, before proceeding to the next coding session.

Answer (score 0):

```
def update
  @website = Website.find(params[:id])
  if params[:website][:language] == "Auto"
    params[:website][:language] = full_language("request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first")
  respond_to do |format|
  if @website.update_attributes(params[:website]) 
    format.html { redirect_to @website, notice: 'website was successfully updated.' }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.js { render action: "edit" }
  end
end
```

end